# Generators of Schwinger Proper Time

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Considering the identity $\frac{1}{A^2} = 
\int ^{\infty}_{0}e^{-sA^2}$ (hope that's correct) $A$ real, one may interpret the propagator as an integral of this exponential quantity over proper time $s$. My question is does this proper time have any actual physical meaning and if so, does it have a generator analogous to how the Hamiltonian generates time flows?

Comment: How did you arrive at your "identity"?

Comment: Note your identity only holds for $\mathrm{Im}(A) >0$. @ACuriousMind See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization.

Comment: @JamalS Thanks, I'll add that in the question, sorry.

Comment: integrating over what, kid?

Comment: @Aierel One doesn't simply integrate, buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help.

Scalar particles are usually treated in the second-quantized form, i.e. in the language of Quantum Field Theory. The particle propagator is thus a certain correlation of the field observables.

But it is possible to use the first-quantized formalism with the action

$$ S[X^{\mu}(\lambda)] = - m c \intop d\lambda \sqrt{g_{\mu \nu} \dot{X}^{\mu} (\lambda) \dot{X}^{\nu} (\lambda)}. $$

If you quantize this theory, you arrive at the same propagator function, given in terms of the proper time $s$. Here's my [detailed derivation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B6q4g_GEl4nFGtcwKWixyplYr8y2MH2E/view?usp=sharing).

Now in this formalism the action is reparametrization-invariant. When you gauge-fix this, you arrive at the reduced description with the Hamiltonian operator which generates shifts in $s$.

However, in the 2nd-quantized description this is obscured.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Cynthia'sLight You're welcome. Btw you can upvote and accept this answer if it helped :)

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I'm trying to learn Feynman's worldline formalism, and found this question. Is the detailed derivation available elsewhere? I believe the link is broken and I think it would help me a little.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1620696 sorry about the broken link, I had to turn my blog down due to personal reasons unfortunately. Here's a Google Drive link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B6q4g_GEl4nFGtcwKWixyplYr8y2MH2E/view?usp=sharing
Let me know if you have any questions!